# How to have multiple extjs apps without duplicating sdk

Tags: extjs4

Following Sencha app layout guidelines for app directory structure I find myself needing a copy of the sdk (e.g. extjs) in each application folder. So I have 2 questions:

1. Can I alias the extjs folder so that only one copy of extjs is shared by multiple apps?
2. If not, how much can I strip out of each copy of the sdk?

I have scoured Sencha docs and the web with no clear answers

Answer (score 0):

You can create .htaccess rules in folders which need to be redirected to shared sdk (for Apache). You can also configure similar rules for other webserver.

Smth like:

```
RewriteRule /app/sdk/(.+)$ /shared/sdk/$1 [R]
```